# Java 'Object.clone' vs Equals ('= ...')

Tags: java, clone

Lately a friend asked me why there's no such thing as the clone function in C#. But I don't really get why to use clone except of this:

```
SomeClass cls = new SomeClass();
SomeClass cls2 = cls;
```

Why would you use = cls.clone();, so like this:

```
SomeClass cls = new SomeClass();
SomeClass cls2 = (SomeClass) cls.clone();
```

I never understood the difference. Can anyone explain which one is better and what the difference is?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you have done here

```
SomeClass cls = new SomeClass();
SomeClass cls2 = cls;
```

Was creating TWO referencec to ONE, same object. Picture (may be a bit ugly because I drew it myself ;)):

[image]

In this code however:

```
SomeClass cls = new SomeClass();
SomeClass cls2 = (SomeClass) cls.clone();
```

You created TWO Objects with TWO references, where the second object is a copy of the first object. cls points to the first object, whilst cls2 points to the second one. Jvm will have to reserve space for two different objects instead of just one. Picture:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The question is always if you want changes to one to affect the other (for mutable objects). For example

```
SomeClass cls = new SomeClass();
SomeClass cls2 = cls; //copies the reference, not the object
cls2.doubleEverything();
```

In the above example there is **only one object** so everything is doubled within the object referenced by `cls2`, which is the same object referenced by `cls1` so they both see the change.

```
SomeClass cls = new SomeClass();
SomeClass cls2 = (SomeClass) cls.clone();
cls2.doubleEverything();
```

There are two objects refered to by two variables, changes to (the object refered to by) cls2 do not affect cls.

<sup>All this assumes that `clone` is implemented correctly, the definition of "correctly" changing on a case by case basis. It may just be a shallow copy, always be wary of `.clone()`</sup>

Answer (score 2):

```
 SomeClass cls = new SomeClass();
```

This is a reference to object SomeClass.

```
 SomeClass cls2 = cls;
```

This is a reference to *same* object.

```
 SomeClass cls3 = (SomeClass) cls.clone();
```

This is a reference to other object that was cloned from original one. Consider next cases

```
 cls2.setState(newState)
```

in this case you will change original object (that is referenced by `cls` and `cls2`).

```
cls3.setState(newState)
```

In this case only `cls3` will be changed. Original object(`cls` and `cls2`) would not be changed.

Answer (score 0):

`clone()` gives you a shallow copy of the original object. The state of the variables will be same as that of the original. `new MyClassObject()` returns a new Object, not cloned or copied one.